# Number-span elision through python

Tags: python

I want to write a code in python for Number-span elision like in the below images

Number spans (such as page ranges) are often abbreviated – for example, 42–43 as 42–3 and 123–128 as 123–8. This is known as number-span elision, abbreviating (or condensing) inclusive numbers, number abbreviation, and, more informally, as digit-dropping.

How to achieve this through python programing

[image]

MWE:

Input:

```
3–10                    
12–18
71–72
96–117
100–104
1100–1113
101–108
808–833
1103–1104
321–328
498–532
1013–1019
1087–1089
1496–1500
11564–11615
12991–13001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the output is always `left`-`right'` where `right'` is `right` but without the common prefix.

Split the input:

```py
left, right = input_string.split("-")
```

Then modify `right`:

```py
def get_shortened_right(left: str, right: str) -> str:
  for i in range(min(len(left), len(right)):
    if left[i] != right[i]:
      break  # stop if not common prefix
  return right[i:]
```

Then you can easily construct the output in the desired format:

```py
final_result = f"{left}-{new_right}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read each input as a string, and then you can split your input into two different parts and check how far apart they are. Something like this:

```
my_input = input("Enter range: ")

my_input = [int(x) for x in my_input.split("-")]

my_input = f"{my_input[0]}-{my_input[1] if int(my_input[1] / 10) != int(my_input[0] / 10) else my_input[1] % 10}"

print(my_input)
```

On this snippet, I split the text (e.g. "122-129") by the '-' and converted it into integers in an array (so [122, 129]). Then I divide both by 10 and I cast it to an integer again because when you cast to an integer, it gets rid of the decimal (like a Math.floor()). If the resulting values are the same, then I can shorten the second number by taking the module of it and 10 (this is the result of dividing the number by 10 and taking what's left, so 129 % 10 = 9)

Comment: Does this handle `11564-11615` -> `11564-615`?